# Data Extension Name vs External Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

The Name identifies the DE in the system whereas the External Key within the scope of API calls. Is there any reason to not give them the same exact value? Anything i am missing about Name vs External Key? Thanks.

Comment: they certainly can have the same value

Comment: @EazyE is there any drawback to giving the name name?

Answer (score 4):

The customer/external key has a 36 character limit, while the name does not. The external also has some character limitations in some places also, I believe.

Comment: According to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314975&type=1&mode=1, the limit 200 characters. Not 36.

Comment: No one's going to know DEs are the exception to the more universal 36 character limit for literally everything else.

Comment: The 200 limit is not capable via the UI, in the UI it is 36 and best practice is to keep it to 36. The 'editing' is done when you change it via API and honestly I have run into issues when doing it this way. It is much more stable and makes more sense to stick to 36 as Adam stated.